# Parallel instances of a Python script

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have researched this topic, but remain confused. I am looking for a straight-forward method to run, concurrently, independent instances of a Python script. The instances don't need to communicate with each other, or even be aware of each other. Simulation software I use takes advantage of Python as it's scripting language. I rountinely run simultaneous simulations on a workstation equipped with 12 cores, by starting each instance from Windows Explorer. This is fine, but a bit cumbersome. There must surely be a way to accomplish this without all of the complexity I find in documentation for the the various multithreading modules I've found online. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: If all you need is to run multiple but separate Python instances simultaneously, simply launch a bunch, as you say. If doing it by hand is too cumbersome,  write a shell script to do it for you. Even in Windows this should not be too hard.

Comment: I'm an engineer, fairly literate with Python, but by no means a professional programmer. Perhaps I have been wrong, but I had the impression that a shell script would require each instance to complete before starting the next. In other words, each instance would execute serially, not concurrently. The Python scripts I want to run in parallel are long, without a lot of OOP bells and whistles. They do things like read flat text data files, call various APIs supplied by the simulation platform I use, then output results to Excel workbooks (via win32com).

Comment: You can definitely launch multiple tasks from a shell, without having to wait for each one to finish. I am not very familiar with shell scripting on Windows, but on Unix you would simply do something like this:

    `python script1.py &`
    `python script2.py &`
    `echo "All Python scripts has been started"`

Here, the `&` makes the job continue in the background, so that you can continue running new commands without waiting for the first to finish. Surely there is some equivalent on Windows.